# Is using a OneToManyResultSetExtractor/ResultSetExtractor with Spring Batch's JdbcCursorItemReader possible?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am just wondering whether using a `OneToManyResultSetExtractor` or a `ResultSetExtractor` with Spring Batch's `JdbcCursorItemReader`?

The issue I have is that the expected `RowMapper` only deals with one object per row and I have a join sql query that returns many rows per object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, it does not support the use of a `ResultSetExtractor`.  The reason for this is that the wrapping `ItemReader` is stateful and needs to be able to keep track of how many rows have been consumed (it wouldn't know otherwise).  The way that type of functionality is typically done in Spring Batch is by using an `ItemProcessor` to enrich the object.  Your `ItemReader` would return the one (of the one to many) and then the `ItemProcessor` would enrich the object with the many.  This is a common pattern in batch processing called the driving query pattern.  You can read more about it in the Spring Batch documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html

That being said, you could also wrap the `JdbcCursorItemReader` with your own implementation that performs the logic of aggregation for you.